# Convert Music File to NSData using MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller

I am using `MPMediaPickerController` to upload music files. When I tried to convert `MPMediaItem` to `NSData`, the `NSData` always returns NULL. 
Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addMusic:(id)sender {
      MPMediaPickerController *soundPicker=[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
      soundPicker.delegate=self;
      soundPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems=NO;
      [self presentViewController:soundPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection{
      MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
      NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
      NSString *audioFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];   
      NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please suggest what can I do to convert `MPMediaItem` to `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these three lines:

```
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSString *audioFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];   
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];
```

Try doing:

```
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:nil error:&error];
if(!audioData)
    NSLog(@"error while reading from %@ - %@", [url absoluteString], [error localizedDescription]);
```

And see if that works better.

If you're interested, what was wrong with the first block of code there was that `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]` probably gives a nil result, since url is a NSURL object and NSString's format is expecting a NSString object.

Comment: I modified my code snippet to show a log line for any errors.  Let me know what error you are getting when trying to read the contents of that URL.

Comment: It returns me error as `The operation couldn’t be completed.`

Comment: getting error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “item.mp3” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=1258203422631791096}

Comment: its giving the same response to me too. @VineeshTP if you got the answer please tell me too